# android getHeight()/getWidth with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, position, android-relativelayout

Hi I'm new to Android and am facing the problem: how do I get the Height/Width of a view,  which is placed in a relative layout? I tried getHeight() and getWidth() and both return 0.

I need to know whether this view has reached the end of the Layout so that I can place the next view to its right or below it.

or maybe there is a better way to do this without knowing the position of the current view?

edit:
I use this code to create an EditText and add it to the layout:

```
                EditText et1 = new EditText(context);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,curView.getId());
                et1.setLayoutParams(p);
                et1.setId(loopid++);
                curLayout.addView(et1);
                curView=et1;
```

and then call:

```
            int[] location=new int[2];
            curView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            Log.d("right:", String.valueOf(location[1]));
```

and it shows a 0.

Comment: use `View.post(new Runnable());`

Comment: could you please provide more detail? I'm new to android. Thank you!

Comment: `location[1]` is the Y coordinate and I think you need the X coordinate (`location[0]`) [ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int[]%29 ]

Comment: you are right but location[0] is also 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling getHeight()/getWidth() before the view can be laid out so it is returning 0. If you call it later in the lifecycle it will stop this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Once your views are created, the UIThread inflates them. So when you instanciate them they have no size.
try using

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = curView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() 
{
    public boolean onPreDraw()
    {
        curView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    }
}
```

Not sure if it'll work though

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("123");
TextPaint paint = button.getPaint();
float len = paint.measureText(button.getText().toString());
```

This len will give buttons width after plus a fixed value