# Dialog Theme Activity Width

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have an activity that uses the Dialog theme.

```
<activity android:name=".GamePreviewDialog" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:label="Chess Set Preview">
```

I can't figure out how to get the width of the dialog. Normally if it wasn't a dialog I would use the getWidth() on the Layout. However doing that on this doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gamePreviewMainLayout"
    android:background="@color/game_background">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gamePreviewButtonView"
        android:id="@+id/gamePreview"
        android:background="@color/game_background">
    </RelativeLayout>           
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:id="@+id/gamePreviewButtonView"
        android:background="@color/background">

        <Button 
            android:text="Close" 
            android:id="@+id/previewCloseBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/chess_mates_btn">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried calling this after my contentView is set like suggested in other posts. Any ideas on how to get the width programatically?

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it is not because of the Dialog theme, it is because it is a RelativeLayout and it doesn't know the width at the time of the onResume. To fix this you use the View.post() method to execute your setup code after the view has been setup. Found this solution here [android getHeight()/getWidth with RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584957/android-getheight-getwidth-with-relativelayout)

Answer (score 0):

as you set layout width FILL_PARENT,you can get the screen size which is your view width now

Answer (score -2):

After `onCreate()` method you can get the height and width.

Comment: How? I have tried calling the getWidth() on my Layout object and it returns 0

Comment: you can get height and width inside the onclick() method of your activity class. i also face this problem but i got solution using above solution.

Comment: You did not answer my question, HOW? call getWidth() on what? On what OnClick()?