# Calculate height of a view after inflating it (not after displaying it)?

Tags: android, layout

I am inflating a layout and trying to get view's height. Here is my code. It always returns 0

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.temp_relative_main_);

int temp_height=item.getHeight();
int temp_width=0;
Log.d("temp_height","temp_height " + temp_height);
```

Comment: post your xml also .What is the height of layout in xml .Is it "wrap content"?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413268/relative-layout-get-width-height-return-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413268/relative-layout-get-width-height-return-0)

Comment: Actually I have added above code in onCreate(..) of an Activity.. I am doing expand collapse animation on a layout and I want to estimate layout height WRAP_CONTENT before passing animator how much to expand